# How to Serialize and Deserialize List<myClass> with protosharp?

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace test_protosharp
{
    [Serializable]
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
    public class MyClass
    {
        [ProtoSharp.Core.Tag(1)]
        [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1)]
        public int MessageType { get; set; }

        [ProtoSharp.Core.Tag(2)]
        [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2)]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static List<MyClass> _forSerialize;

        static void Main()
        {
            _forSerialize = new List<MyClass>
                                {
                                    new MyClass {MessageType = 0, Message = "Test1"},
                                    new MyClass {MessageType = 1, Message = "Test2"},
                                    new MyClass {MessageType = 2, Message = "Test3"},
                                    new MyClass {MessageType = 3, Message = "Test4"}
                                };

            // Test BinaryFormatter Serializer
            using (Stream fs = File.Create("test.bin"))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                bin.Serialize(fs, _forSerialize);
            }

            using (Stream fs = File.OpenRead("test.bin"))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                _forSerialize = (List<MyClass>)bin.Deserialize(fs);
            }

            if (_forSerialize.Count == 4)
                Console.WriteLine("BinaryFormatter serializer work");

            // Test protobuf-net Serializer
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create("test.protobuf-net"))
                ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(fs, _forSerialize);

            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("test.protobuf-net"))
                _forSerialize = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<List<MyClass>>(fs);

            if (_forSerialize.Count == 4)
                Console.WriteLine("protobuf-net serializer work");

            // Test ProtoSharp Serializer
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create("test.ProtoSharp"))
                ProtoSharp.Core.Serializer.Serialize(fs, _forSerialize);

            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("test.ProtoSharp"))
                _forSerialize = ProtoSharp.Core.Serializer.Deserialize<List<MyClass>>(fs);

            if (_forSerialize.Count != 4)
                Console.WriteLine("ProtoSharp serializer NOT work");            

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

protosharp doesn't support lists as root objects; you will need to wrap it:

```
public class SomeWrapper
{
    private readonly List<MyClass> items = new List<MyClass>();
    [ProtoSharp.Core.Tag(1)]
    public List<MyClass> Items { get { return items; } }
}
...
var tmp = new SomeWrapper();

tmp.Items.AddRange(_forSerialize);
using (FileStream fs = File.Create("test.ProtoSharp"))
    ProtoSharp.Core.Serializer.Serialize(fs, tmp);

using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("test.ProtoSharp"))
    _forSerialize = ProtoSharp.Core.Serializer.Deserialize<SomeWrapper>(fs).Items;

if (_forSerialize.Count == 4)
    Console.WriteLine("ProtoSharp serializer work");
```

This should then be identical (in terms of bytes) to the protobuf-net output.

I will, however, suggest (perhaps not very humbly) that protobuf-net does the same job but has been extensive refined and optimised far beyond what protosharp offers, additionally with support for many many more scenarios.

--

Edit: interestingly, they are *not* identical outputs; protosharp has 2 extra bytes... I'll see if I can find out why... edit-edit: ah, that is just the zero-default behaviour; don't worry about that. For info, if you make `MessageType` as follows, the outputs of the two protobuf-based serializers is (as you would hope and expect) 100% identical:

```
[ProtoSharp.Core.Tag(1)]
[ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true)]
public int MessageType { get; set; }
```